# Merge installed packages to new org using unlocked packages

Tags: unlocked-package

Since unlocked packages are quite new, I'm wondering what their limitations are. For example i want to merge an installed package (in this case the Sumo App) using unlocked packages to a new org. Is that possible/advisable with App Exchange Apps or would you try the migration with another tool like GearSet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can build an Unlocked Package that depends on one or more packages. You still have to install those packages as a prerequisite to installing the Unlocked Package, but this can be done. There's no need to include the installed metadata (which you can't fully access anyways), just create the package with dependencies, install those dependencies, then install the package. No external tools other than Salesforce DX is required.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say you cannot re-package metadata from an installed (managed) package into any other package.